# Are candles appropriate at work?

Tags: professionalism, company-culture, unprofessional-behavior

I've recently gotten back into drinking tea, and have increased my volume of consumption significantly. I sometimes make tea 3-4 times a day. It is getting tedious to make it seperately each time, so I was considering getting a teapot for my desk.

However the teapot would quickly get cold, unless I also bring one of those small stands that use tea candles to keep your teapot warm. However this introduces the need for candles.

Would this be considered appropriate at your office? The candles would be unscented of course. The only objection that I can think of is that it may be a fire hazard.

Comment: Have you considered a tea cosy? Also how could making tea a maximum of once every 2 hours be tedious, if you work with computers you're meant to take screen-breaks at double that rate.

Comment: Have you considered using a thermos flask/can for your tea?

Answer (score 15):

I think open flames in an office would be discouraged. There are other ways to keep a container of liquid hot. There are USB mug heaters that draw power from your computer, there are electric hot plates, and if your office has a microwave, you can reheat a cool tea in that.

Answer (score 8):

Fire hazard indeed. I would be shocked if you employer's safety office -- or insurer -- approved this. It's hard enough getting permission for an electric heater; most companies will insist that it be a pre-approved model (if any have been approved) .

I recommend (a) asking your own employer, and (b) seriously considering a vacuum-insulated container to keep things warm, rather than a heat source at the desk. It's not peffect but it's good enough to reduce trips for refills.

Or think of the trip to get another cuupa as a chance for a break and a stretch, rather than an inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

> Would this be considered appropriate at your office?

No, it wouldn't. And I've never worked in an office where open flames would be permitted. In my office, we have an instant hot water system, and the tea-drinkers rely on that.

Check with your office manager (or someone else in charge at your site), for specifics for your office.

Have you considered an electrical equivalent, so that you don't need a flame?

Comment: Even electrical may require safety office approval, and even if they approve it they may insist on just having one shared unit in a break room or kitchenette.

Comment: Don't forget we do get questions for countries where "elf and safety" is not as developed as it is in the USA/UK/EU I could see this happening in some Asian countries

Answer (score 2):

In our office, we have a water boiler that can keep water hot enough to make tea all day.  People come and make a cup of tea at a time and refill it as needed.  Perhaps you can get something like that for your office.